# Missing a sequence when using itertools combonations_with_replacement

Tags: python, set, python-itertools

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

x = 'opo'
v = combinations_with_replacement(x, len(x))
ans = [''.join(map(str, x)) for x in v]
print(" ".join(set(ans)))
```

I'm not sure why im missing the sequence `pop` here. Why does `pop` not show but `ppo` and `opp` do .

expected output `opp ppp poo ppo ooo opo  oop pop`

actual output `opp ppp poo ppo ooo opo oop`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
>>> x = 'abc'
>>> v = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(x, len(x))
>>> ans = [''.join(map(str, x)) for x in v]
>>> ans
['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'abb', 'abc', 'acc', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bcc', 'ccc']
```

The *values* in the sequence are irrelevant to what `combinations_with_replacement` does; only the positions within the sequence count.  Your question is the same as asking why `'bab'` and `'cac`' don't show up in my example.  Hint:  the name of the function isn't `permutations_with_replacement` ;-)

Comment: Pretty much the explanation I was getting to, except faster and better :).

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement): "Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, the generated combinations will also be unique."

Answer (score 1):

It is documented correctly [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) -

> **itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)**
>
> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable allowing individual elements to be repeated more than once.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.
>
> **Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value**. So if the input elements are unique, the generated combinations will also be unique.

Emphasis mine.